# Visual Studio: Disable Auto Copy text on doubleclicking inside of it

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I don't know how this was turned on, when I double click inside a word it's auto copied to the clipboard in the Visual Studio IDE (it occurs with ANY filetype).
I looked through options for Resharper and Visual Studio and found nothing that adresses it.

Any insight? The only plugin I use is resharper and I suspended it but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Is it happening in visual studio only or in other programs also?
Try it in notepad. If it is happening in notepad also then there might be some other software which is causing this.